Error unable to publish shared module extension to webstore
Has anyone ever worked with an extension that has a shared module format?
I'm encountering issues when publishing the application to the store.
The error I'm facing is as shown in the attached image.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I've tried on several developer accounts but still couldn't get it to work.

Apparently it's not implemented in the official web store.
